# Python syntax can not recognise Azerbaijani alphabet in a string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the web pages with the method of creating links but the problem happens when there is an Azerbaijani alphabet inside of the link. Python split link from where an Azerbaijani alphabet starts.

AN EXAMPLE:

link should be like =>
[http://marja.az/search?q=ali+əli](http://marja.az/search?q=ali+%C9%99li)

but it prints it like =>
http://marja.az/search?q=ali+əli

**CODE:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import locale


URL = 'http://marja.az/search?q='

# if there is a prabel inside of keyword merge with + sign
KEYWORDS = [
           'Vali+Vəli'
           ]

for key in KEYWORDS:
    search_url = URL + key
    print(search_url)
    r = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")
    for data in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "searchNews"}):
        for a in data.find_all("a"):
            href = a.get("href")
            link = "http://marja.az/" + href
            print(link)
            r1 = requests.get(link)
            soup1 = bs(r1.content, "lxml")
            # HEADER of NEWS
            header = soup1.find("h1", attrs={"class": "title"}).text
            print(header)
            # CONTENT of NEWS
            paragraph = soup1.find("div", attrs={"class": "text"}).findAll('p', text=True, recursive=False)
            for p in paragraph:
                print(p.text)
            # DATE of NEWS PUBLISHED
            date = soup1.find('div', {'style': 'color: #af0000; margin:10px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:12px; ''font'
                                               '-weight:bold; text-align:left;'}).text
            date = date.split(",")[0].split(" ")
            date = date[0] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[2]
            print(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output tof your script is 100% plain text - there is nothing after doing "print" **in the Python language** that would convert a printed URL to a working link.

It is the tool you are using to view your program output that does so - whether you are running your program in a terminal emulator, inside an IDE or inside Jupyter notebook, it is that program that tries to convert strings starting with `https://` into working links and is failing at this character.

So, while this has nothing to do with Python behavior, there is one thing you can try: to escape that part of the URL prior to printing it - maybe the offending program will recognize the whole URL.

For that, do:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote

...
# and later on the code replace this line:
             # link = "http://marja.az/" + href
             # for
             link = "http://marja.az/" + quote(href)
```

If that does not work, you will have to resort to writting your own output interface, be it a web page, or a Tkinter window, that will properly use your link - and, of course, you can file a bug against whatever program you are using to run your script in - its that program's fault that the character from a different alphabet is not being considered a part of the URL.

Comment: the problem happens in the line of `search_url = URL + key    print(search_url)` 
The search_url not giving the desired result as printed in question

Comment: so, qhote the  `key` . It is still as I have written.

Comment: it prints search_url like http://marja.az/search?q=ali%2B%C9%99li but it should be like [http://marja.az/search?q=ali+əli]

Comment: Yest - it is quoted, but it now _works_ . If it prints the unicode characters you want **the program** you are running Pthn into won't format the URL correctly and won't work. You have 3 options: change the progrm you are using to run Python in to one that works, to _view_ the URL with all characters in a beautiful way (what you aready had), or to have it working, and it have to use escape codes and be "ugly". And that is it.